# Что такое Unicode и как с ним связана UTF-8

Tags: unicode

Со страницей википедии про Unicode ознакомился, но так и не понял, хотя там и написано что это стандарт кодирования символов

Насколько я знаю то Unicode представлен следующим образом

> 0x00000000 — 0x0010F800

Есть такое утверждение, что UTF-16 = Unicode, так ли это?

UTF-16 представлен как 256*256 = 65 536 (без суррогатных пар), с суррогатными парами формула такая 2^20+2^16−2048 - тут не ясно как такая формула получилась, кто сведущ объясните (без суррогатных пар все ясно)

UTF-8 представлен следующим образом

> **4 байта (то что используется)**
>
> 0x00000000 — 0x001FFFFF
>
> **6 байта (то что не используется)**
>
> 0x00000000 — 0x7FFFFFFF

Тут как бы назревает вопрос а как мы можем переводить из UTF-8 в Unicode если Unicode кодирует в 2 раза меньше символов?

Что такое Unicode и зачем в него переводить допустим из той же самой UTF-8?

P.S Каша в голове, запутался уже X_X, помогите проявить ясность в голове

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47702/discussion-on-question-by-maximpro---unicode------utf-8).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<sub>Резюмируя написанное в комментариях и чате. Примечание: данный ответ не претендует на строгую спецификацию, а является объяснением «на пальцах» для улучшения понимания и может содержать неточности, а для разработки программ лучше читать не SO и даже не Википедию, а [непосредственно сам стандарт](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/UnicodeStandard-10.0.pdf).</sub>

В контексте вопроса **Unicode** — это просто **табличка символов** и закреплённых за ними **целых чисел** (не каких-либо байт, а обычных человеческих чисел). (А ещё юникод описывает обработку символов и их преобразования друг в друга, но вопрос не про это.)

Кусочек этой таблички:

[image: Кириллица в Юникоде]

Эта табличка не указывает, как именно эти числа переводить в байты, которые можно было бы сохранить в компьютере. Но, чтобы хранить юникод в компьютере, кто-то должен указать, как их всё-таки переводить!

---

Возьмём числа из этой таблички символов и запихнём их в **четыре байта** так, чтобы четыре байта представляли **беззнаковое целое число** (unsigned int, uint32). То есть, например, из кода буквы «Я» 42F<sub>16</sub> получаем байты `00 00 04 2F`. Таким образом мы получили простейшую **кодировку UTF-32** (UTF-32-BE<sup>1</sup>, UCS-4). Если интерпретировать эти полученные четыре байта как беззнаковое целое число, то мы получим номер символа в табличке Unicode.

С уточнением, что мы используем uint32, можно для себя считать, что **UTF-32 = Unicode**: каждое число кодируется-декодируется как есть без каких-либо преобразований.

---

Если мы возьмём числа из таблички и запихнём их в **два байта**, представляющие беззнаковое целое число (unsigned short, uint16), то мы получили бы **первую версию Юникода**, которая была в 1991 году. Тогда число символов было ограничено 65536, и все их коды можно было легко представить двумя байтами без дополнительных преобразований.

Но потом решили, что 65 тысяч это как-то мало, и увеличили максимальное количество символов до миллиона. Но ведь миллион в два байта уже никак не запихнёшь, и нужно взять больше байт на символ. Но так как уже успели появиться программы, рассчитывающие на эти самые два байта (например, в Java или Windows NT длина одного символа до сих пор 2 байта), то для сохранения хоть какой-то обратной совместимости из этих двух байт выдрали диапазон D800<sub>16</sub>..DFFF<sub>16</sub> и сказали, что это суррогатные пары, занимающие по четыре байта и обрабатывающиеся по особому [алгоритму](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.BF_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F) для символов с кодом 10000<sub>16</sub> и больше. И назвали всё это **кодировкой UTF-16**.

Таким образом, в UTF-16 числа из таблички юникода, попадающие в диапазоны 0000<sub>16</sub>..D7FF<sub>16</sub> и E000<sub>16</sub>..FFFF<sub>16</sub>, записываются в два байта как есть, а символы с кодами 10000<sub>16</sub> и больше записываются в виде суррогатных пар с использованием диапазона D800<sub>16</sub>..DFFF<sub>16</sub> и занимают четыре байта. Так старые приложения, сделанные под первую двухбайтовую версию Юникода, смогли продолжить и дальше с ним работать, если не используются суррогатные пары.

Таким образом та же буква «Я» (код 42F<sub>16</sub>) представляется в UTF-16 (UTF-16-BE) как `04 2F`, а символ «» с кодом 1F512<sub>16</sub>, не влезающим в два байта, по алгоритму преобразуется в четыре байта `D8 3D DD 12`.

Из-за этих самых суррогатных пар с кучей преобразований **UTF-16 ≠ Unicode**.

---

**UTF-8** была сделана для совместимости с ASCII: в ней коды символов от 0 до 7F<sub>16</sub> записываются в один байт как есть, в итоге выдавая этот самый ASCII, а всё остальное кодируется по алгоритмам ещё более хитрым, чем в UTF-16, поэтому **UTF-8 ≠ Unicode** тоже.

Технически UTF-8 позволяет закодировать числа аж до двух миллиардов, однако Unicode ограничен миллионом символов, и стандартом установлено, что **кодировать в UTF-8 числа, не входящие в допустимый диапазон Unicode, запрещено**. Поэтому проблемы перевода из UTF-8 в Unicode чисел, не входящих в Unicode, просто нет: хорошо сделанное приложение в таких случаях выкинет ошибку или заменит всё недопустимое символом �.

---

В Notepad и Notepad++ можно наблюдать кодировку, названную «Unicode», но на самом деле это UTF-16-LE с BOM<sup>1</sup>.

<sub>(клик для увеличения)</sub>

[image]

---

Самой распространённой кодировкой вроде как является UTF-8.

---

<sup>1</sup> — числа, занимающие более одного байта, можно записывать с разным [порядком байт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2): например, число 259 можно записать как `01 03` (big endian, BE) или как `03 01` (little endian, LE). То же самое применимо к символам в кодировках UTF-16, UTF-32 и некоторым другим (но не UTF-8). Вышеупомянутый  кодируется в UTF-16-LE неё как `3D D8 12 DD` — в то время как в UTF-16-BE это будет `D8 3D DD 12`. [BOM — это специальный символ FEFF<sub>16</sub>](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) в начале текста, который позволяет определить этот самый порядок байт — в big endian он пишется как `FE FF`, а в little endian как `FF FE`, а использование символа FFFE<sub>16</sub> запрещено, что и позволяет определить порядок байт.

Comment: Хороший ответ, осталось только пояснить формулу: `2 ^ 20 + 2 ^ 16 − 2 048 = 1 112 064`

Comment: @MaximPro `2 ^ 16 − 2 048` — два байта (16 бит) на символ минус диапазон для суррогатных пар, `2 ^ 20` — столько символов можно записать в суррогатных парах согласно тому хитрому алгоритму (20 бит на символ, первые 10 бит в первых двух байтах пары, вторые 10 бит во вторых двух байтах пары, подробности в википедии)

Comment: Все спасибо, потом еще википедию гляну =)

Comment: Вы великолепно объясняете, очень понятным языком. Понравилось читать. Одно замечание: вы вводите понятия endianness (неявно, черезн упоминание BE и LE) и BOM, но не объясняете их.