# char в linux поддерживает юникод из коробки?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, unicode

Вот задался неистовым вопросом, я передаю в функцию из [си](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8) строку с типом `const char*` которая содержит в себе юникод символы *(это могут быть любые азиатские/русские символы, или специфичные символы не поддерживаемые `ASCII`)*. В режиме отладки наблюдаю ситуацию, все символы мало того что корректно отображаются в отладчике, так еще и [си](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8) функция получая ее корректно работает.

[image: Unicode]
[image: Unicode2]

Это магия, или в `Linux` `char` сразу содержит в себе 2 байта а не 1?

Comment: В Linux дефолтная кодировка UTF-8 которая нормально вмещается в однобайтовый `char`. Т.е. нулевых символов внутри такой строки нету, но и один символ может занимать сразу несколько `char`.

Comment: Про кодировку системы понятно, но вот как это понять? `но и один символ может занимать сразу несколько char.`

Comment: @LLENN один символ из UTF-8 хранится в нескольких байтах-char'ах

Comment: *как это понять?* — [читайте до просветления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). или [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575494/178576)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/595299/178988

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, у тебя просто исходник в UTF8: https://ideone.com/IAZE6i

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
  const char *s = "Это моя строка";
  unsigned n = strlen(s);

  printf("%d\n%s\n", n, s);

  for (unsigned q=0; q<n; ++q)
    if (s[q] & 128)
      printf("%.2s %u %u\n", s+q, s[q] & 255, s[q+1] & 255), ++q;
    else
      printf("%.1s %u\n", s+q, s[q] & 255);

  return 0;
}
```

```
26
Это моя строка
Э 208 173
т 209 130
о 208 190
  32
м 208 188
о 208 190
я 209 143
  32
с 209 129
т 209 130
р 209 128
о 208 190
к 208 186
а 208 176
```

Comment: Хм, да исходник в UTF8, но строка передаваемая в метод, не статическая, что-то тут не чисто. Я не понимаю как мне быть с выделением памяти под строки.

Comment: @LLENN, значит источник, из которого ты получаешь строку, тоже использует utf-8.

Comment: @LLENN: Как это вам мешает выделять память под строки? Срока `s`, как обычно, требует `strlen(s) + 1` байтов памяти. Вот если вы пальцем по экрану будете буковки считать, то память может получиться неправильная, но просто не надо так делать.

Comment: @AnT: Я не такой пример имел ввиду, а то что мне было не понятно, как в `Windows` у меня строки с `utf8` отображались как `?`, а тут... Вот и появился вопрос, подумал что размер у `char` не 1 байт, или просто магия.