# Почему для кодирования одного символа нужен именно 1 байт?

Tags: кодировка

Почему для кодирования 1-го символа нужен именно 1 байт?

Я прекрасно понимаю, что минимальная единица информации - 1 бит и чтобы выразить 255 символов в двоичном коде надо использовать 8 бит. И по таблице брать двоичный код и по нему находить нужный символ, но почему каждый символ обязательно занимает 1 байт? Зачем записывать число именно вот так `0000001`, а не просто `1`, тем самым заняв всего 1 бит информации и по таблице взять ему соответствующий символ.

Comment: Байт - минимальная адресуемая единица информации. Хранить каждый символ меньше чем в одном байте неэффективно по скорости доступа. А для длительного хранения (при сохранении в файл, например) никто не мешает применить сжатие.

Comment: @insolor, Use the answer form, Luke!

Comment: Символы не хранят в одном байте уже лет тридцать :)

Comment: А вообще теоретически использовать один бит не разрешает, только вот `11111111` — это один символ (число 255) или восемь символов `1`? Придётся добавлять дополнительную информацию, поясняющую, как правильно интерпретировать эти единицы. Ну и да, использовать число битов меньшее чем «минимальная адресуемая единица информации» банально неудобно, ибо именно под восьмибитный байт спроектированы все современные компьютеры

Comment: @andreymal, о спасибо большое! Теперь дошло! Только вот еще вопрос тоесть большие последовательности в зависимости от кодировки делятся на определенное количество байт (1, 2 и тд) и уже по таблице находится определенные символы ?

Comment: @НикитаАнтонов большие последовательности декодируются (как именно — зависит от кодировки) в число, обозначающее номер символа в юникоде, а дальше уже этот номер смотрится по табличке. Подробнее я рассказывал тут: [Что такое Unicode и как с ним связана UTF-8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575494)

Comment: @andreymal, еще раз спасибо за объяснения!

Comment: (наверно из этих комментов можно сбацать полноценный ответ, но полный ответ подразумевает объяснение, почему байт восьмибитный и почему байт вообще существует, а я не знаю, так что от написания ответа воздержусь)

Comment: @andreymal, для базового уровня этого пока хватит :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не обязательно 1 ..есть кодировки (например utf-16, utf-32 ) где символы по 2 , по 4 байта. тут еще многое зависит от  количества кодируемых символов. не всегда хватает 256 вариантов. часто нужно больше.то есть битность напрямую зависит от числа символов в  таблице символов. 
Если влезть в ассемблер, то можно сделать свою таблицу символов. проблема будет только в том что твою кодировку будет понимать только твоя программа. 
А так просто принятый стандарт, и все. 
по поводу же адресации, да - опять же стандарт. хотя есть системы , которые работают и 9-ю битами ( старые советские системы связи) , где 9-й бит был или контрольным или знак передавал.

Comment: Я наверное неправильно задал вопрос имею в виду почему все символы имеют 1 и тот же размер(тоесть 2 байта или 1), а не так чтобы 1 символ весит больше, а другой меньше, если все равно старшие разряды заполнены нулями (00000001 к примеру)

Comment: @НикитаАнтонов в кодировке UTF-8 длина одного символа может быть 1, 2, 3 или 4 байта :) А использовать число бит, не кратное восьми, неудобно из-за архитектуры современных компьютеров, заточенных именно на 8 бит

Comment: будут проблемы с синхронизацией. такая проблема есть в азбуке морзе. то есть трудно понять где закончился один символ и начался второй. поэтому и принято использовать такие битности.

Comment: @Сергей Петрашко, Спасибо, дошло теперь!

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, есть код Хаффмана, там эта проблема решается. Но это полезно именно при сжатии (при хранении на диске, например).

Comment: это все понятно, есть и другие вариации  решения такой проблемы,  общий то смысл такой, как  уже все написали. общий посыл понятен,не стоит сильно углубляться.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, если тема интересная, почему бы не углубиться)

Comment: да блин помню в совке делали такую штуку как полуторный бит для разделения символов и переменное число бит. но это больше для систем связи, чем вычислительных систем.  свертки различные и так далее.